# Concat strings in Java

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, strings

I've written this function that concats strings:

```
public void find(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {
  String toMerge = operations.get(1);
  String fromMerge = operations.get(2);
  outer: for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
     String[] toSet = set.get(i).split(" ");
     for (int k = 0; k < toSet.length; k++) {
    if (toMerge.equals(toSet[k])) {
        for (int j = 0; j < set.size(); j++) {
        String[] fromSet = set.get(j).split(" ");
        for (int x = 0; x < fromSet.length; x++) {
            if (fromMerge.equals(fromSet[x])) {
            for (int c = 0; c < toSet.length; c++) {
                set.set(j, set.get(j)+ ' ' +  toMerge.concat(' ' +toSet[c]));
                set.set(i, " ");
                }
                break outer;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This function takes as parameter an `arrayList` of operations, and an `arrayList` of set:

1. For the `arrayList` of `operations`, I always get a specific position, so I don't iterate.  It is always \$O(1)\$.
2. for the `arrayList` of set, I have to iterate, or rather, as I think of that to proceed:

   For example, if I have as operation `move foo bar`, I have to do these steps:

   - First of all, I have to find where foo is:

     - Inside `set`, I can have this situation:

       ```
       position x : {bar tree hotel}
       ...
       position y : {foo lemon coffee}
       ```
     - When I find the string `foo`, I have to find the position of `bar` (I made an iteration as to find `foo`) and then i have to  concat the `foo string into bar string`  in this way:

       ```
       position x : {bar tree hotel foo lemon coffee}
       ...
       position y : {}
       ```

My program works as well as my function, but it is a nasty and inefficient solution.  **How can I improve the efficiency of this function?**

Comment: Looks like you've been changing your code back and forth, and the two versions are significantly different. If you're actively improving your code, perhaps wait until you're sure about the change. -- Couldn't you knock down some time by getting an index of the substring with `.indexOf(String)`, then doing the concat with the index with `.substring(index, yourString.length())`?

Comment: @BobbyDigital now it is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what it looks like you're trying to do:

1. loop through `set`, loop through each individual word in `set`, until you find `toMerge`.
2. When you find that, you then restart the loop through `set`, and each word in `set` until you find `fromMerge`.

This is producing a redundancy in the case that your initial loop iterates over `fromMerge`, but continues the loop because it is only looking for `toMerge`. The approach I would take to improve it would be to search for both in the same loop, thereby eliminating the redundant second loop.

```
public void find(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {
    String toMerge = operations.get(1);
    String fromMerge = operations.get(2);
    int toMergeIndex = -1, fromMergeIndex = -1; //add search indexes
    for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
        if (set.get(i).indexOf(toMerge) > -1)
            toMergeIndex = i;
        if (set.get(i).indexOf(fromMerge) > -1)
            fromMergeIndex = i;
        if (toMergeIndex != -1 && fromMergeIndex != -1)
            break;
    if (toMergeIndex == -1 || fromMergeIndex == -1){
        throw new Exception();//Failed, didn't find. Deal with as you wish   
    }
    else{
        set.get(fromMergeIndex) += " " + set.get(toMergeIndex);
        set.get(toMergeIndex) = " ";
    }
```

This is the only **efficiency** improvement that I can think of. Hope it helps!

Comment: good solution,really appreciate it.